# Can Picard’s existence and uniqueness theorem be proved by using the implicit function theorem？

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I was recently researching the relationship between ODEs and the implicit function theorem, and in a bachelor thesis https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1249251/FULLTEXT01.pdf I found an application of The Implicit Function Theorem to ODEs:

> 5.3.1. Differential equations: There is a strong relation between the implicit function
> theorem and a theorem for the existence of solutions to differential equations. For
> example, a typical existence theorem for ordinary differential equations is the Picard’s
> existence and uniqueness theorem [9], which can be proved by using a generalization
> of the Implicit Function Theorem for general Banach spaces.

Picard’s existence and uniqueness theorem (Picard–Lindelöf theorem)：

> Let ${\displaystyle D\subseteq \mathbb {R} \times \mathbb {R} ^{n}}$be a closed rectangle with ${\displaystyle (t_{0},y_{0})\in D}{\displaystyle (t_{0},y_{0})\in D}$. Let ${\displaystyle f:D\to \mathbb {R} ^{n}}{\displaystyle f:D\to \mathbb {R} ^{n}}$ be a function that is continuous in $t$ and Lipschitz continuous in $y$. Then, there exists some $ε > 0$ such that the initial value problem
> $y'(t)=f(t,y(t)),\qquad y(t_0)=y_0.$
> has a unique solution $y(t)$ on the interval ${\displaystyle [t_{0}-\varepsilon ,t_{0}+\varepsilon ]}[t_{0}-\varepsilon ,t_{0}+\varepsilon ]$.
> Note that $D$ is often instead required to be open but even under such an assumption, the proof only uses a closed rectangle within $D$.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem

But in the conditions of the theorems in the papers and books I found later, the continuous function $f(x,y)$in the equation$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}=f(t,y)$ is strengthened to $C^r(r>0)$ and not only satisfy the Lipschitz condition for $y$.
So my question is: ***Is it possible to proof Picard’s existence and uniqueness theorem ($f$ satisfies the Lipschitz condition for $y$) by using a a general implicit function theorem?***

The articles I found：
Picard–Lindelöf theorem in Fréchet spaces(f is $C^m$):
http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm137/sm13721.pdf

Picard–Lindelöf theorem in Banach spaces(f is $C^r$):
https://web.archive.org/web/20180724204029id_/https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1968-019-04/S0002-9939-1968-0227583-0/S0002-9939-1968-0227583-0.pdf

```
                                              --------2022.7.18 02:13:02
```

Following @JaapEldering comment, I found information about "Lipschitz Implicit Function Theorem" in a note:
(Notes on the Implicit Function Theorem by KC Border)

> Theorem 6 (Lipschitz Implicit Function Theorem) Let P be a compact
> metric space and let $f : R × P → R$ be continuous and assume that there are
> real numbers $0 < m < M$ such that for each $p$ $$m⩽\frac{f(x,p)−f(y,p)}{x−y} ⩽M.$$Then there is a unique function $ξ : P → R$ satisfying $f(ξ(p), p)
> = 0$. Moreover,$ξ$ is continuous.

I don't know is it enough to proof ***The Theorem*** I have mentioned.

```
                                              --------2022.7.18 17:17:24
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain it should be doable to prove the Picard-Lindelöf theorem for functions $f$ that are only Lipschitz in $x$ using the implicit function theorem, in the same way as in the paper by Robbin (1968) that you linked, but to do so you need a Lipschitz version of the implicit function theorem (which exists). That is, if you have an implicit function $F(x,y)$, such that $F(0,0) = 0$ and $F$ is bi-Lipschitz in $x$ and Lipschitz in $y$, then it follows that there exists a Lipschitz function $G$ on a neighborhood of $y = 0$, such that $F(G(y),y) = 0$.

Comment: @JaapEldering I've edited the post to add the theorem that might be needed. Could you please introduce some literature about this kind of proof or the way how to search for relevant literature?

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at the following paper by Nijenhuis titled Strong derivatives and Inverse mappings in American Math Monthly vol 81 no 9 pages 969-980 .

Comment: I don't really know about literature on this topic, I've just looked into this this myself a little bit (when I was still in academia). Also, you probably need a more general version of that Lipschitz implicit function theorem, where also the first argument lives in a complete metric space. I should be a matter of combining the proofs of that theorem and the normal implicit function theorem in Banach spaces. Then follow the proof in Robbin's paper and where he applies the C^r implicit function theorem, use the Lipschitz one instead. Sorry, that's a bit general...

Comment: @MohanRamachandran : Thanks for your help, this should be the proof I'm looking for.

Comment: @JaapEldering : Thanks for your help, these should be some useful clues.